# IInAppBillingService.aidl cannot generate Java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to use in app product purchase in Android App, I tried to put IInAppBillingService.aidl in many places but no one generates the Java file , here is my structure of App:

[image]

Could someone help me to find where I am wrong ?

Note: I am use using Android Studio.

Answer (score 45):

There is some misplacement of directories in your project as shown in attached screenshot.

Your **main** directory should be inside the **src** directory and `IInAppBillingService.aidl` must be on the below mentioned path

```
/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl
```

so create a directory inside your main and then create the package as mentioned and put your .aidl file inside.

Make the necessary changes and sync Your project with gradle.

Comment: great, enjoy playing  with studio.

Comment: Official docs are not clear enough for android studio. Thank you

Comment: When you finish with directory, after that must Rebuild Project.

Comment: This answer helped because it made me **SYNC my gradle**.  IAB documentation is so old...

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for it on the aidl folder which was wrong assumption.The java file will generate on the build, source, aidl folder.. hope this helps